# How can I split the content of a tag to multiple tags via regex?

Tags: regex, xml-parsing

I have a XML file with hundreds of tags which looks like this:

```
<entry id="1">
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <tags>kw1,kw2,kw3</tags>
</entry>

[...]

<entry id="200">
  <title>Title 200</title>
  <tags>kw3</tags>
</entry>
```

Now, instead of the ***tags*** tags I have to add ***tag*** tags for every entry inside:

```
<entry id="1">
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <tag>kw1</tag>
  <tag>kw2</tag>
  <tag>kw3</tag>
</entry>

...

<entry id="200">
  <title>Title 200</title>
  <tag>kw3</tag>
</entry>
```

So is it possible to split the original tags and add its contents to new ones via regex?

Comment: You will be better looking for a parser solution

Answer (score 2):

Use a parser as per this answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

There are a lot of problems using regex to doing this.

Comment: This is true but if the format is well known, a very short `sed` is much easier and works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to replace `tags` with `tag`..you can use the following to match:

```
(<\/?)tags>
```

and replace with:

```
$1tag>
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3vQ0/4)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly in the DEMO link.

Comment: @SoHo What is the problem that you observed? i checked and all `tags` were replaced with `tag`

Comment: I believe that the question was about how to split the contents of one tag into many, not simply replace one with another.